# Как посчитать количество совпадающих строк в листбоксе?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть listbox1 с семью строками: 3 строки "apple" и 4 строки "orange". Если ввести в textBox1 слово: "app". Тогда нужно чтоб в label1 выдало число 3, потому что есть 3 совпадения в listbox1.Items. Как посчитать количество строк содержащих текст из textBox в listbox'е? Можно это сделать с помощью Contains?
Следующий код выдает количество всех строк:

```
label1.Text = main.listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
```

А как вывести число тех строк которые совпадают с текстом из textBox?

Comment: По аналогии с предыдущим вашим вопросом. Только не нужен второй цикл, а вместо прерывания цикла при совпадении поставьте увеличение счетчика

Comment: @rdorn: а можно тот код с прерыванием цикла (в том вопросе) и этот код (не нужен второй цикл, а вместо прерывания цикла при совпадении поставьте увеличение счетчика) как-то их объединить? Пытался их объединить, но не получилось.

Comment: нет, объединить их нельзя, задачи разные - способы решения разные.

Comment: То что код внешне похож, не значит, что он работает одинаково.

Comment: @rdorn: Не могли бы вы показать пример кода. Плохо разбираюсь в циклах. Пробую, но не получается.

Comment: Если плохо разбираетесь с циклами, самое время взять "скучную" книжку по алгоритмам и разобраться с основами. При всем уважении, без элементарной базы вы так и останетесь на уровне "найти и скопипастить". Тут не самое удачное место для развернутых лекций начального уровня, да и подготовка подобного материала требует массу времени, так что придется читать самостоятельно. Проскочить мимо базовых алгоритмов (циклы и их применение в том числе), увы, не получится. Конкретный  язык программирования, в данном случае, значения не имеет, просто не спешите, читайте, пробуйте прочитанное и все получится.

Answer (score 1):

- > А как вывести число тех строк которые совпадают с текстом из textBox?

`label1.Text = main.listBox1.Items.Count(x => x.Value.Contains(textBox1.Text));`
Там где Value - само значение которое содержат контролы, которые ты используешь в ListBox. Но, сначала подключаешь библиотеку `using System.Linq`, вроде всё.